# Adding TransactionSynchronizationRegistry in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

I'm trying to use '`TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`' via EJB injection in a session bean. However during deployment on a weblogic App Server i got the error that '`TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`' is not properly defined in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml. I tried to do that but with no success so far. I tried doing the following:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.0/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar">
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>asdas</ejb-name>
    <resource-description>
      <res-ref-name>TransactionSynchronizationRegistry</res-ref-name>
      <jndi-name>java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry</jndi-name>
    </resource-description>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: `@Resource TransactionSynchronizationRegistry tsr` should be sufficient.  Please show the full error output.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work. I was doing the injection as such:

```
@Resource
TransactionSynchronizationRegistry trx;
```

so instead of modifying weblogic-ejb-jar.xml, i modified the injection to become as such:

```
@Resource (mappedName = "java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry")
TransactionSynchronizationRegistry trx;
```

It worked!